# Copying a mobile version of a website?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I'm currently creating an offline version of quite a popular website for simulation purposes (no copyright).

I've successfully created an offline version of the desktop version but I'm having issues getting the mobile version

I've spoofed my user-agent to emulate a mobile device through google chrome, and visited the website and when i view source the codes looks ok, but it for some reason doesn't load correctly....

Is there a better way of doing this?

The current code I have is taken from www.o2.co.uk

Comment: Share plunker/fiddle for better understanding. Or post your code.

Comment: It's too long to fit in this page but its here; http://plnkr.co/edit/42rBeNW5KUK01i7NP5eF?p=preview

Comment: The weird thing is, it actually loads the content on plunker, however it doesn't load it on my browser!

Comment: A responsive site will be based from screen resolution and not user agent, so you'd need to try loading it with your browser viewport set to that of a mobile device. http://whatismyviewport.com/

Comment: But when I try loading it with a different viewport, it shows the full desktop version (of my simulated version)

Comment: I noticed the same. it is working on plunker but not my local.